# How to avoid showing duplicated data in different row?

Tags: javascript, database

I am trying to show the record returned from my DB

my returned data is like the following:

```
UserID   Username    Fullname     ID
141        john       jerry1      170   
141        john       jerry1      18
141        john       jerry1      1169
110        ted       jerrytest    1701
110        ted       jerrytest    18
```

I want to show all the ID in the page but avoid the duplicated username

so it will be like

```
john    170
        18
        1169

ted     1701
        18
//I only want 2 divs (for john and ted) instead of 5.
```

My codes currently show

```
john    170    //1 loop
john    18     //1 loop
john    1169   //1 loop

ted     1701   //1 loop
ted     18     //1 loop
```

My codes:

```
for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
  //create a div for each row...in my case, 5 divs/rows


//i tried to create a var a
   a=i-1;
   if(results[a]){
        if(results[i].Username==results[a].Username){
           continue;
        }
    }


//this will eliminate the duplicated john and ted but only show john 170 and ted 1701.

}
```

To recap, I want to show all the unique id in each row but not the duplcated username. 
Are there better way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I sometimes do it that way, works fine. Either that or you restructure your data so that it's something more like `[141,'john','jerry1',[170,18,1169]]`.

Comment: in my case, I can't do anything about the data structure. (I wish I could)

Comment: Why not? You just have the pre-process the data right before you run your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not combine both methods?

```
var endResult = "",
    ids = [],
    userName;

for (var i = 0, lt = results.length; i < lt; i++)
{
    ids.push(results[i].ID);
    userName = (i === 0 || results[i].Username != results[i-1].Username) ? results[i].Username : false;

    if (userName)
    {
        endResult += "<div>" + userName + "</div>";
        endresult += "<div>" + ids.join("<br>") + "</div>"

        //Reset the list of ids
        ids = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution kind of work for me. I forget to mention that I only want 2 divs (for john and ted) in my end result instead of 5 divs. +1 though

Comment: Ok, no problem.  I've edited the code to take that into account.  It's off the top of my head, though, so it's untested.